# Loop Through Specific Associative Array In PHP

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

I am trying to loop through only a specific sub array in PHP with foreach.  Example array:

```
$testData = array(  
    $test1=array(  
        'testname'=>'Test This',
        'testaction'=>'create user',
         $testData = array(
             'item'=>'value',
             'foo'=>'bar',
             'xyz'=>'value'
         ),
         $anotherArray = array()
     ),
     $test2=array(  
        'testname'=>'Test That',
        'testaction'=>'get user',
         $testData = array(
             'item'=>'value',
             'foo'=>'bar',
             'xyz'=>'value'
         ),
         $anotherArray = array()
     )
);
```

And now I am going to go through each test and set some logic based on the name and action, but then need to do several tests on the data.  Not sure how to only get $test1's $testData and not $test1's $anotherArray data. I have the following but it doesn't work:

```
foreach($testData as $test => $section){
    foreach($section['testData'] as $field => $value){
        \\code
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `$testData1` is not a properly constructed array. You should've received an error. Using Laverdure's answer, you can access your data by using, `$testData['test1']['testData']`.

Comment: what are you referring to with `$testData1` @Josh

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I just meant `$testData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$testData = array(  
'test1'=>array(  
    'testname'=>'Test This',
    'testaction'=>'create user',
    'testData' => array(
         'item'=>'value',
         'foo'=>'bar',
         'xyz'=>'value'
     ),
     'anotherArray' => array()
 ),
 'test2'=>array(  
    'testname'=>'Test That',
    'testaction'=>'get user',
    'testData' => array(
         'item'=>'value',
         'foo'=>'bar',
         'xyz'=>'value'
     ),
     'anotherArray' => array()
 )
);
```